# Product image is being uploaded but is not appearing on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, frontend, image-upload, small-image

**EDITED**

I am loading product by cron, this function reads whole dir, gets all files names i.e **test_16_008_NL.png** here test_16_008_NL is sku of product, then it loads add entries in tables **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery** , catalog_product_entity_media_**gallery**_value and **catalog_product_entity_varchar**, like all entries by uploading manually from admin.
Product image is being uploaded, can be view from backed, Also present in db and in disk in folder **media >> catalog >> product**,  but not appearing on front end. I have checked folder permission, deleted cache, indexed data and deleted .htaccess file under media folder, what I am missing?

**CASE**

Image is appeared on front if I go to admin and open a product i.e **test_16_008_NL** product just have to save.Otherwise image is not appearing.My store is **multiple store** and uploded file look like this 
[image: uploaded image]

my cron call is

```
public function importImagesFromDisk() {
        $filename = array();
        $sourcePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS;

        if (is_dir($sourcePath)) {
            if ($dir = opendir($sourcePath)) {
                while (($value1 = readdir($dir)) !== false) {//reading whole directory
                    $filename [] = $value1;
                }
                closedir($dir);
            }
        }

        $productUpdate = array();
        $productFile = array();
        foreach ($filename as $fName) {

            if (pathinfo($fName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {//is it a file
                $name = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $fName); //Drop extension of file
                $_productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($name);

                if ($_productId) {
                    $productUpdate[$_productId] = 'Insert';
                    $productFile[$_productId] = $fName;
                }
            }
        }

        $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
        $mediaGalleryAttributeId = $installer->getAttribute($entityTypeId, 'media_gallery', 'attribute_id'); //Get attribute_id of attribute "media_gallery"
        $smallImageAttributeId = $installer->getAttribute($entityTypeId, 'small_image', 'attribute_id'); //Get attribute_id of attribute "small_image"

        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore('admin')->getId(); //As admin store is used for uploading images

        $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); // To read from the database
        $cpevTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar');

        $query = "SELECT value_id, value, entity_id FROM " . $cpevTable . " WHERE attribute_id= " . $smallImageAttributeId;
        $result = $read->query($query); //Execute query
        //Fetch row one by one from result
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $fields = array();
            $fields['value'] = $row['value'];

            if (array_key_exists($row['entity_id'], $productUpdate)) {
                $productUpdate[$row['entity_id']] = $row['value_id'];
            }
        }

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); // For writing into database
        $write->beginTransaction();

        foreach ($productUpdate as $productID => $update) {

            $file = $productFile[$productID];
            $fileName = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file); //Drop extension of file
            $parentFolder = $fileName[0];
            $childFolder = $fileName[1] ? $fileName[1] : '_';

            $destinationPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product' . DS . $parentFolder . DS . $childFolder . DS;
            if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
                //Creating folder with write permission
                mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, true);
            }
            try {
                if (copy($sourcePath . $file, $destinationPath . $file)) {//Copy file from $source location to destination
                    $imagePath = DS . $parentFolder . DS . $childFolder . DS . $file; //Path used in db to refer image

                    $mediaGalleryFields = array();
                    $mediaGalleryFields['attribute_id'] = $mediaGalleryAttributeId;
                    $mediaGalleryFields['entity_id'] = $productID;
                    $mediaGalleryFields['value'] = $imagePath;

                    $write->insert('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery', $mediaGalleryFields);
                    $write->commit();

                    $lastInsertId = $write->fetchOne('SELECT last_insert_id()');

                    $mediaGalleryValueFields = array();
                    $mediaGalleryValueFields['value_id'] = $lastInsertId;
                    $mediaGalleryValueFields['store_id'] = $storeId;
//                        $mediaGalleryValueFields['label'] = $imagePath;//By default Null will be placed
                    $mediaGalleryValueFields['position'] = 1;
                    $mediaGalleryValueFields['disabled'] = 0;

                    $write->insert('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value', $mediaGalleryValueFields);
                    $write->commit();

                    $catalogProductFields = array();
                    $catalogProductFields['entity_type_id'] = $entityTypeId;
                    $catalogProductFields['attribute_id'] = $smallImageAttributeId;
                    $catalogProductFields['store_id'] = $storeId;
                    $catalogProductFields['entity_id'] = $productID;
                    $catalogProductFields['value'] = $imagePath;

                    if ($update != 'Insert') {
                        $write_connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                        $where = $write_connection->quoteInto('value_id =?', $update);
                        $write_connection->update('catalog_product_entity_varchar', $catalogProductFields, $where);
                    } else {
                        $write->insert('catalog_product_entity_varchar', $catalogProductFields);
                        $write->commit();
                    }

                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
                    $_product->save();

                    unlink($sourcePath . $file); //Delete file from source directory
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache(); //Clear images Cache
    }
```

Comment: You haven't selected all the options, all but 1 are set not to display

Comment: @SR_Magento that doesn't matter, because I am displaying on base of **small_image**, that is set

Answer (score 3):

If it's a multiple store make sure you have added the image on default store.

Also in your store under image tab make sure check box been marked.

[image]

Comment: please see updated post

Comment: I am already doing this

Comment: Fine, Let me check!!

Comment: have you checked it